# Shell script: Call variable with parameters/arg

Tags: bash, variable, function

I have the following function in a bash script:

testcur.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash

function valcurl {

    if [[ $1 != "" ]] then

        tbl=$2     # can be multiple values
        data=/home/data
        btic=$data/$tbl"_btic"
        kline=$data/$tbl"_kline"

        if [[ "$1" == "btic" ]] then
            errbtic=$data/$tbl"_btic_err"
        elif [[ "$1" == "kline" ]] then
            errkline=$data/$tbl"_kline_err"
        fi

        # how do I replace the parameter $1 to call the variable?
        cat $1 | jq . 2> $"err"$1     
                
        if [[ -z $"err"$1 ]] then
            echo "correct"
        else
            echo "contain error"
        fi
    else
        echo "Not var found, only btic or kline"
    fi
}

valcurl $1 $2
```

Is this possible or is there another way?

Comment: what does call the variable mean?

Comment: Why define two *different* variables for the error output filename when it's its value that needs to be different, not the variable name? Just use `$errout` and set it to the right filename depending on `$1`.

Comment: This script run with multiples values, i have edited the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want the error output to go to a specific file depending on one of the arguments to your function.  For this, you don't need two separate variables:

```
if [[ "$1" == "btic" ]]; then
    err="$data/${tbl}_btic_err"
elif [[ "$1" == "kline" ]]; then
    err="$data/${tbl}_kline_err"
fi
```

or just

```
err="$data/${tbl}_${1}_err"
```

Then call `jq`:

```
jq . <"$1"  2>"$err"
```

---

I noticed several issues with your code and I have tried to sort them out below:

```
#!/bin/bash

valcurl () {

    if [ "$1" != 'btic' ] && [ "$1" != 'kline' ]; then
        echo 'first argument has to be btic or kline' >&2
        return 1
    fi
    if [ -z "$2" ]; then
        echo 'second argument must not be empty' >&2
        return 1
    fi

    datadir=/home/data

    datafile="$datadir/${2}_$1"
    err="${datafile}_err"

    if jq . <"$datafile" 2>"$err"; then
        echo 'correct'
    else
        echo 'contains error'
    fi
}

valcurl "$1" "$2"
```

I have assumed that it is the data file constructed by using the first and second argument that you want to send through `jq`, and that you want to check `jq`'s exit status for failures.  `jq` would fail if `$datafile` is not a valid JSON file.

I've also shortened the code a bit by not creating separate variables for each variation of `$1`, and then added some validation of the arguments.